# C# I'm having trouble with a dice game where I need to increment a value every time a user plays a game and then print it back to them

Tags: c#, increment, dice

I have a dice game which holds two dice and what happens is that one game will go through and then the user will be asked if they want to play again. If, for example, they said yes three times then when they say no at the end to exit the game, they'll get an output telling them how many times they played the game. I'm having trouble coming up with the code for it.

I don't have much experience using parameters and return types(this is a beginner assignment) but I currently have a counter which adds 1. The problem is that it starts at 0 and goes to 1, and then stays there.

Here's the code I have that runs through the game:

```
namespace MajorAssignment1
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hey! Welcome to Ray's Dice Game! Let's Start");
            Console.WriteLine();
            EvenOrOdds();

        }

        public static void EvenOrOdds()
        {

            Random rnd = new Random();

            int die1 = rnd.Next(1, 10);
            int die2 = rnd.Next(1, 10);

            Console.WriteLine("Die 1 = {0} and Die 2 = {1}", die1, die2);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("You Rolled {0} and {1}", die1, die2);
            Console.WriteLine();

            if ((die1 + die2) % 2 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Evens are better than odd.");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            if ((die1 + die2) % 2 > 0 )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Odds are still cool.");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }


            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play again? Please enter in all caps YES or NO");
            String UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
            var Counter = 0;
            if (UserInput == "YES")
            {
                EvenOrOdds();

                Counter = Counter + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The number of times the dice was thrown is:" + Counter);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }



        }

        public static void Outro()
        { 
                Console.WriteLine("Thanks for playing! Come again!");
                Console.WriteLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `var Counter = 0;` does? How often is that line executed? Once? More then once? Is that what you want it to do? Also: try to play lots of times. You might run out of stack space.

Comment: I wouldn't use recursion here but some loop.

Comment: Better return a bool for EvenOrOdds and give it Counter as a parameter. See if you can use a loop, for example a while loop

Comment: I thought that the var counter = 0 would have the counter start out at 0 while the counter + 1 would increment it everytime a user ran it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with your code is that you are calling `EvenOrOdds()` *recursively*, and `counter` never increments. Moreover, you are doing simple things in a complicated way, I have simplified few things.

**Working code:**

```
using System;
public class diceCounter
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String UserInput;
        int Counter =1;
        Console.WriteLine("Hey! Welcome to Ray's Dice Game! Let's Start");
        Console.WriteLine();
        do
        {
            EvenOrOdds();
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play again? Please enter in all caps YES or NO");
            UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
            if (UserInput.Equals("YES"))
            {
                Counter++;
                EvenOrOdds();
            }
        }while(!(UserInput.Equals("NO")));

        Console.WriteLine("The number of times the dice was thrown is: " + Counter);
        Outro();
    }

    public static void EvenOrOdds()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int die1 = rnd.Next(1, 10);
        int die2 = rnd.Next(1, 10);

        Console.WriteLine("Die 1 = {0} and Die 2 = {1}", die1, die2);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("You Rolled {0} and {1}", die1, die2);
        Console.WriteLine();

        if ((die1 + die2) % 2 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Evens are better than odd.");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        if ((die1 + die2) % 2 > 0 )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Odds are still cool.");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

    }

    public static void Outro()
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("\nThanks for playing! Come again!\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to have worked. Thanks! I guess I should've done my increments at the start and not have it equal to zero.

Comment: @lostclubb yes you understood your issue rightly, however do accept it as answer if it helped you thats how SO works :)

Comment: @lostclubb New users must take this to account, that if they find the answer correct and it resolves their issue, then kindly mark that as answer. so that if someone have the same issue in future they can get a handy help without asking a new question. That's how things work here . Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 1):

By calling EvenOrOdds() from within itself in order to "play again", you are effectively creating a recursive call to the function.

You are re-defining Counter within the scope of each instance of EvenOrOdds() you are calling, resulting in Counter always ending up as 1.

One easy option is to move the definition of Counter out into a class-level variable, which then means it will be shared between all your calls to EvenOrOdds()

```
class MainClass
    {
        //class-level static variable
        private static int Counter;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hey! Welcome to Ray's Dice Game! Let's Start");
            Console.WriteLine();
            EvenOrOdds();

        }

// rest of code here
```

Which then means you can remove the definition of Counter within your EvenOrOdds() code. Now when you increment Counter it is updating the class-level variable, which will result in your expected Counter behaviour.

```
Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play again? Please enter in all caps YES or NO");
String UserInput = Console.ReadLine();

if (UserInput == "YES")
{
    //increment the counter first
    Counter = Counter + 1;

    //then call the method again for a new game
    EvenOrOdds();

}
```

Also you could change "Counter = Counter + 1;" line you use the inline ++ increment operator: "Counter++ ;" which will do the same thing.

**Note**: There are other ways to implement this type of "play again" functionality which would be better, such as using loops etc, but without rewriting what you have already done significantly my advice above will suffice as a minor change that achieves what you want to do. Good luck!

**Edit:** Updated to increment Counter first, before calling EventOrOdds() again - which results in Counter being correctly incremented for each game played.

Comment: I did so but now it seems to be stuck at the number 0. I added the private int at the top and got rid of the var counter = 0. Is there anything else that I am missing out on?

Comment: Oh, found it - ran the code myself in debug. It turns out need to do the Counter++ (or Counter = Counter + 1) increment **before** you call EvenOrOdds() again:

`if (UserInput == "YES")
{
 Counter++;

 EvenOrOdds();

}`

Answer (score 0):

I can come up with two solutions

1) use a private variable at class level. Remember to remove the definition for counter at your method

```
class MainClass {
private static int Counter = 0;
...
}
```

2) send a ref parameter to your method

```
public static void EvenOrOdds(ref int counter)
```

and in main
    EventOrOdds(counter). the same goes for your recursion